# julia: Is it possible to name dataframes stored within an array

Tags: dataframe, filesystems, julia

I have ~500 files stored within a folder. Here is a small subset of them:

```
 "10.0.0.txt"
 "1.0.0.txt" 
 "10.1.2.txt"
 "10.1.3.txt"
 "10.1.4.txt"
 "10.1.5.txt"
 "10.2.1.txt"
 "10.2.3.txt"
 "10.2.4.txt"
 "10.2.5.txt"
 "10.3.1.txt"
 "10.3.2.txt"
 "10.3.4.txt"           
 "Y.3.1.txt" 
 "Y.3.2.txt" 
 "Y.3.4.txt" 
 "Y.3.5.txt" 
 "Y.4.1.txt" 
 "Y.4.2.txt" 
 "Y.4.3.txt" 
 "Y.4.5.txt" 
 "Y.5.1.txt" 
 "Y.5.2.txt" 
 "Y.5.3.txt" 
 "Y.5.4.txt"
```

I want to read them all into Julia and be able to call them by names. Currently I am using the below code:

```
df = CSV.read.(filter(r"^", readdir()); delim=' '; header=["chrom", "pos", "ref", "alt"], )
```

This reads all files in the current working directory into an array of dataframes, which is what I want. However, is there a way to name each dataframe (or array index) so that I can call the specific dataframe I require by it's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to create a dictionary mapping names to `DataFrame`s, e.g. (I have changed the regex a bit as I guess you want to leave names ending with `txt`):

```
Dict((f, CSV.read(f, delim=' ', header=["chrom", "pos", "ref", "alt"]))
     for f in filter(r"txt$", readdir()))
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually if possible I would like to remove the ".txt" from all names?

Comment: Replace `f` in `... (f, CSV.read ...` part by `f[1:end-4]` in Julia 0.6 (this is the simplest but not the safest as Julia uses byte indexing not character indexing). In Julia 0.7 you can write `chop(f, tail=4)` to remove last 4 characters from a string. If you want to be safe in Julia 0.6 then `replace("adas.txt", r"\.txt$", "")` is a clean way to do it.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!